# How to specify kernel while executing a Jupyter notebook using Papermill's Python client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, papermill

I am running a jupyter notebook script using Papermill's python client. While running, I want to specify the kernel. However, the script ran within the same kernel as my active python shell(through which I made the API call to papermill in order to run the notebook's script).

I tried looking in the documentation(https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-execute.html#execute-via-the-python-api) but in vain.

```
import papermill as pm
pm.execute_notebook( 'dfnjofnei.ipynb', 'dfnjofnei_output.ipynb' )
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is too late now, but you can check this:

```
papermill {input_path} {output_path} -k {kernel_name}
```

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is not comprehensive. You can find other configurable args here: https://github.com/nteract/papermill/blob/main/papermill/execute.py

To specify the kernel when calling the API, just supply `kernel_name`, for example:

```
import papermill as pm
pm.execute_notebook(
    'input.ipynb',
    kernel_name='python3'
)
```

(I tried that and it worked)